# How can I display a list of objects within a list of objects, with a multi value header

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am trying to display a list of objects that contain a list of objects. I have gone down a few rabbit holes, including grouping ObservableCollections but haven't been able to implement the right approach. From what I can tell, grouping only uses a single title/key (can anyone confirm this?).

For context, I am making a barcode scanning Android app for vehicle loading using Xamarin Forms and C#.

I have an object for a Shipping Order, which is the parent item, with the labels Order Ref, Cust Name and Delivery Date.

Within this object there are multiple Shipping Items, listed Item 1, Item 2 etc.

I have mocked up a rough example of how I would like the data to be structured in the view. I want to be able to bind all of these entries, so background colours can be changed when the items are scanned, and the parent colour changed when all items for the order have been fulfilled.

I'd be grateful if you could point me in the right direction.

[UI Mock Up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uz2uG.png)

--Edit--
Thanks for the guidance, I seem to be going round in circles with Grouping, though i'm clearly missing something. I can get a test case working, following tutorials with simple data but I'm struggling to adapt it to my models. I've added a simplified version of them below, would grouping work with these models or do I need to change the way i'm thinking about this??

**ShippingOrder Model**

```
    public class ShippingOrder
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string OrderRef { get; set; }
    public string CustName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DeliveryDate { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<ShippingItem> ShippingItems { 
get; set; }
}
```

**ShippingItem Model**

```
public class ShippingItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ShippingOrderId { get; set; }
    public string ItemDescription { get; set; }
    public bool IsLoaded { get; set; }
}
```

**Shipment Model**

```
public class Shipment
   

 {
        public int ShipmentId { get; set; }
        public string VehicleId { get; set; }
        public DateTime DepartureDate { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<ShippingOrder> ShippingOrders 
{ get; set; }

        public Shipment()
        {
            // Generate mock data.
            ShipmentId = 1;
            VehicleId = "Trailer 3";
            DepartureDate = DateTime.Parse("05/08/2022");
            ShippingOrders = new 
ObservableCollection<ShippingOrder> ();

            //Order 1
            ShippingOrder shippingOrder1 = new ShippingOrder();
            shippingOrder1.Id = 1;
            shippingOrder1.OrderRef = "001";
            shippingOrder1.CustName = "John Smith";
            shippingOrder1.DeliveryDate = 
DateTime.Parse("06/08/2022");

            shippingOrder1.ShippingItems = new 
ObservableCollection<ShippingItem>();
            shippingOrder1.ShippingItems.Add(new ShippingItem {Id 
= 1, ShippingOrderId = 1, IsLoaded = false, ItemDescription = 
"Large Box" });
            shippingOrder1.ShippingItems.Add(new ShippingItem { 
Id = 2, ShippingOrderId = 1, IsLoaded = false, ItemDescription = 
"Medium Box" });
ShippingOrders.Add(shippingOrder1);


            //Order 2
            ShippingOrder shippingOrder2 = new ShippingOrder();
            shippingOrder2.Id = 2;
            shippingOrder2.OrderRef = "002";
            shippingOrder2.CustName = "Dwayne Dibley";
            shippingOrder2.DeliveryDate = 
DateTime.Parse("06/08/2022");

            shippingOrder2.ShippingItems = new 
ObservableCollection<ShippingItem>();
            shippingOrder2.ShippingItems.Add(new ShippingItem { 
Id = 3, ShippingOrderId = 2, IsLoaded = false, ItemDescription = 
"Small Box" });
            shippingOrder2.ShippingItems.Add(new ShippingItem { 
Id = 4, ShippingOrderId = 2, IsLoaded = false, ItemDescription = 
"Small Box" });
            shippingOrder2.ShippingItems.Add(new ShippingItem { 
Id = 5, ShippingOrderId = 2, IsLoaded = false, ItemDescription = 
"Medium Envelope" });
ShippingOrders.Add(shippingOrder2);


            // Order 3
            ShippingOrder shippingOrder3 = new ShippingOrder();
            shippingOrder3.Id = 3;
            shippingOrder3.OrderRef = "003";
            shippingOrder3.CustName = "Paul Ramone";
            shippingOrder3.DeliveryDate = 
DateTime.Parse("06/08/2022");
            shippingOrder3.ShippingItems = new 
ObservableCollection<ShippingItem>();
            shippingOrder3.ShippingItems.Add(new ShippingItem { 
Id = 6, ShippingOrderId = 3, IsLoaded = false, ItemDescription = 
"Large Box" });
            shippingOrder3.ShippingItems.Add(new ShippingItem { 
Id = 8, ShippingOrderId = 3, IsLoaded = false, ItemDescription = 
"Small Box" });

ShippingOrders.Add(shippingOrder3);

        }
    }
```

Comment: https://docs.devexpress.com/MobileControls/DevExpress.XamarinForms.DataGrid.DataGridView I think that this can help you

Comment: You should be able to do this with Grouping by creating a composite key for the group.  You can also try nesting but this generally isn’t a good idea

Comment: I've done this exact thing in the past with Grouping, using a composite key (as @Jason mentioned). The key might be a combination of Order Ref, Cust Name and Delivery Date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No reason to overcomplicate it too bad.

You need to create a grouping class to hold your items:

```
public class ShippingItemGroup : ObservableCollection<ShippingItem>
{
    public ShippingOrder Shipment { get; private set; }

    public ShippingItemGroup(ShippingOrder shipment, ObservableCollection<ShippingItem> shippingItems) : base(shippingItems)
    {
        Shipment = shipment;
    }
}
```

In your view model or page, set up your ObservableCollection and add your items to it:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var shipment = new Shipment();

    foreach (var item in shipment.ShippingOrders)
    {
        ShippingItems.Add(new ShippingItemGroup(item, item.ShippingItems));
    }

    BindingContext = this;
}

public ObservableCollection<ShippingItemGroup> ShippingItems { get; private set; } = new ObservableCollection<ShippingItemGroup>();
```

Finally setup your CollectionView:

```
<CollectionView IsGrouped="True" ItemsSource="{Binding ShippingItems}">
    <CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="LightBlue" HeightRequest="45">
                <Label Text="{Binding Shipment.OrderRef}" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                <Label Text="{Binding Shipment.CustName}" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                <Label Text="{Binding Shipment.DeliveryDate}" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" />
            </StackLayout>                    
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Text="{Binding ItemDescription}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

Running Result:

[image]

Style as desired.

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks so much for that. A simple and elegant solution. Exactly what i'm after.

Comment: I have this working great now, I have added a property to the Shipping Item class called BacgroundColour, which stores the hex colour as a string and binds to the Background property of the ItemDescription label. When I change the hex value in the grouped list, it doesn't refresh the UI. Is there a way to correctly bind the value so it updates? I've tried OnPropertyChanged in the ShippingItem model, but it fails.

Comment: Ask a new question so we can see the code and we'll take a look at it